# jqGrid selects row only once, subsequently cannot select any other row, grid stuck

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I've got a jqGrid along with a jquery UI button toolbar. My toolbar consists of View & Edit Mode. In my jqGrid onSelectRow I check edit mode with method isInEditMode. This returns true if the button with ui-active-state is edit button.

My grid seems loads correctly, and hover classes turn on/off as a drag my mouse over the rows. If I'm not in edit mode and click a row it does other functionality, which is correct. But when isInEditMode returns true it only seems to allow onSelectRow to fire ONCE.

Many thanks for all the help.

```
var lastselTsg;

grid.jqGrid({
        colNames: ['BudgetId', 'BudgetAccountId', 'Account #', 'Name', 'Cost', 'StaticRowId', 'SortOrder'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'BudgetId', index: 'BudgetId', hidden: true, edithidden: true },
            { name: 'BudgetAccountId', index: 'BudgetAccountId', hidden: true, edithidden: true },
            { name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', sortable: false, width: 70 },
            { name: 'BudgetName', index: 'BudgetName', sortable: false, width: 230, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {
                defaultValue: "",
                dataInitInit: function (el) {
                    var value = $(el).val();

                    value = value.replace("<strong>", "");
                    value = value.replace("</strong>", "");

                    $(el).val(value);
                    $(el).focus();

                    if (value == "") {
                        $(el).remove();

                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            },
            { name: 'TotalCost', index: 'TotalCost', sortable: false, formatter: totalCurrencyFormatter, width: 100 },
            { name: 'StaticRowId', index: 'StaticRowId', sortable: false, hidden: true, edithidden: true },
            { name: 'SortOrder', index: 'SortOrder', sortable: false, hidden: true, edithidden: true }
        ],
        pager: pager,
        pgbuttons: false,
        pginput: false,
        rowlist: [],
        sortname: 'SortOrder',
        rowNum: 99999999,
        sortorder: "asc",
        datatype: "json",
        viewrecords: true,
        url: url + "GetLoad",
        editurl: url + "SaveGrid/",
        loadComplete: function (data) {

        },
        onSelectRow: function (rowId) {
            if (isInEditMode(budgetId)) {
                if (rowId && rowId !== lastselTsg) {

                    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastselTsg);

                    var rowData = grid.jqGrid("getRowData", rowId);
                    if (rowData != undefined && rowData != null) {
                        console.debug("entering edit mode");    

                        grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowId, true, '', '', url + 'SaveTopSheet', {
                            budgetAccountId: rowData.BudgetAccountId
                        }, 
                        function(rowid, response) {
                            console.debug("aftersave: reloadGrid");
                            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
                        }, '', function(rowid, reuslt) {
                            console.debug("after restore: reloadGrid");
                            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
                        });

                    }

                    lastselTsg = rowId;
                }
            } else {
                var getRowData = $("#baseTopSheetGrid" + budgetId).jqGrid('getRowData');
                var rowData = getRowData[rowId - 1];

                onSelectGridRow(rowData);
            }
        },
        gridComplete: function () {

            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            var getRowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');

            if ($.isFunction(budgetGridLoadComplete))
                budgetGridLoadComplete(getRowData);

        }
    }).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else` part inside of `onSelectRow` event handle looks like a little strange. You should better not call `onSelectRow` inside of `onSelectRow` and the usage of `getRowData` inside of the same `else` code fragment seems me also wrong (the `rowId` should be parameter of the function).

Comment: the onSelectrow(rowData) is a function passed into the method that generates the grid. I've changed to name of the function to avoid any future conflict, but I'm still receiving the issue.

Comment: Currently the code which you post has many references to external functions (`isInEditMode`, `onSelectGridRow`, `budgetGridLoadComplete`). So your problem can not be reproduced. The problem which you describe not exist in a simple jqGrid. If you want that somebody fix your problem you should post a code with which other people can reproduce your problem.